# Composer for windows could not be downloaded SSL: Handshake timed out

Tags: php

This is what I get when I try to install composer for windows

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   SSL: Handshake timed out
>
> Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation failed'

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Make sure the `php_openssl` extension is enabled in your PHP CLI `php.ini`

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe , Use This file and download composer. Make sure you have `php_openssl` enabled

Comment: i have openssl enabled but still gives me "Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Handshake timed out
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol "

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1

Run below command in terminal

```
composer config --global disable-tls true
composer config --global secure-http false
```

## Step 2

Add  "secure-http": false in composer.json file

```
"config": {
    "secure-http": false
},
```

## Step 3

Run below command in terminal

```
composer clear-cache
composer diagnose
```