# Error installing laravel using composer Windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, windows, composer-php

Tried to install laravel using this method.

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

And this error comes up:

**[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/p/laravel/installer.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Handshake 
timed out
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed**

Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score -1):

try disabling firewall / antivirus on your PC if u have.

Comment: tried the method but the same error occur

Comment: @khel then check the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893248/composer-for-windows-could-not-be-downloaded-ssl-handshake-timed-out
as mentioned above

Comment: @khel then check the answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893248/composer-for-windows-could-not-be-downloaded-ssl-handshake-timed-out
as mentioned above